# Group isomorphic to $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a certain group theory question am I asked to show that groups $G$ and $D_4$ are isomorphic, where $D_4$ is the diedric group of order $8$ (eight elements, involving the figure of a square). In my case, $G$ is a subgroup of $S_4$. I need to find an isomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow D_4$. I only wanted to know if just choosing $\phi(\sigma_1) = a, \phi(\sigma_2) = b$, where $a$ is the element of the diedric group of order $4$ (the rotation) and $b$ the element of order $2$ (the symmetry), such that ${\sigma_1}^3 \sigma_2 = \sigma_2 \sigma_1$ it would be enough. Note that this last equality is the presentation of this diedric group.

In order to simplify: if I find two permutations in a certain subgroup of $S_4$ (indeed, it is the centralizer of $(12)(34)$ such that the composition of those two permutations satisfy the presentation of the diedric group, is that enough to define the application $\phi$? Do I need any other condition to be satisfied?

Comment: It should be noted that they're not isomorphic: $|D_4|=8$ and $|S_4|=4!$.

Comment: I'm saying that $D_4$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$, not to $S_4$